# CDI/JSF How to handle session timeout

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2

I have a Jakarta EE8 ( CDI 2 / Weld / JSF 2.3 / Wildfly ) app where I need to execute some cleanup code when the user logs out, manual logout are fine however I now need to fire an event when logout happens automatically due to session timeout, to handle this I have tried the following two methods already...

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class HttpSessionObservers implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Inject private Logger log;
    @Inject SecurityContext securityContext;

    @PreDestroy
    public void processSessionScopedDestroying() {
        
        log.debug("Http Session predestroy");   
        Principal principal = securityContext.getCallerPrincipal(); //<----is null
        //...do some cleanup/logging operations on user account
    }

}
```

The above `@PreDestroy` callback fires when the session times out but the logged in user (principal) is always null so it seems they have already been logged out so I cannot obtain the user.

```
@Named
public class HttpSessionObservers implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Inject private Logger log;
    @Inject private Event<UserLogoutEvent> userLogoutEvent;
    
    public void processSessionScopedInit(@Observes @Initialized(SessionScoped.class) HttpSession payload) {
        log.debug("Http Session initialised");
    }

    public void processSessionScopedDestroying(@Observes @BeforeDestroyed(SessionScoped.class) HttpSession payload) {
        //Never fires
        log.debug("Http Session predestroy");   
        Principal principal = securityContext.getCallerPrincipal();
        //...do some cleanup/logging operations on user account
    }

    public void processSessionScopedDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(SessionScoped.class) HttpSession payload) {
        log.debug("Http Session destroyed");    
    }
}
```

Here, the @BeforeDestroyed event is never fired, cannot seem to find any examples of this working, it does work ok for other scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own `HttpSessionListener` and annotate it with `@WebListener` The container should recognize this and will call the the `sessionDestroyed()` method in your implementation. Your class is eligible for CDI Injection so in `sessionDestroyed()`, you can fire an event and listen for it with a CDI Observer.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html

## EDIT:

Try this then: Scope your `HttpSessionListener` impl to `@ApplicationScoped`. Have a synchronized Map of sessionId/username. In `sessionCreated()` insert into the map,  and on `sessionDestroyed()` remove it in a `finally` block.

The container will also have several implicit `HttpSessionListener`s, so there's a chance yours is being called last long after the session is invalidated. If thats the case, there's another technique you can use to insert your `HttpSessionListener` impl first. Try the above technique first then we can dive into this.

Comment: I just tested this and its the same problem as the @PreDestroy callback, the Principal is null so I cannot retrieve the logged in user

Comment: @DaveB any luck?

Comment: Good suggestion, actually I already have an ApplicationScoped map of sessions that I can call on to do this so I will go down that route, its a shame that the @PreDestroy callback doesn't work as I hoped it would and give me access to the logged in user

Comment: I will see if anyone else can provide a more direct solution, otherwise if not will mark this as correct

Comment: Sounds good Dave. If you have a app scoped map of session, I would suggest using a `HttpSessionListener` to maintain it so you don't accidentally leak memory. 

We're using a similar setup to push a "You've been timed out" notification over a websocket. We intercept the session invalidation with a `HttpSessionListener` and push a message over a websocket to inform the user.